# Is something happening network-wide related to Turkey?

Tags: discussion, spam

Yesterday, I noticed that pretty much the entire front page of Travel was last edited by Community. By and large, the questions related to Turkey. I went to one of the questions, and there was a deleted answer that was hidden as spam. I clicked the user to see if they had any remaining "answers" that might need flagging, but there weren't any, so I thought no more of it.

Today I notice pretty much the entire first page of History (where I have less rep and can't see deleted content) is also last edited by Community, and these questions all concern Turkey. Is something going on here that people who are able to flag could help with?

Comment: Yes, it are golden days if you want to work on your flag-weight ...

Comment: Same thing seems to have happened (on a smaller scale) on Politics.

Comment: Sure it was Community? I checked now and all those are made by a multi-account troll which call themselves "The Away Days" on Travel. From what I know, it's a known network wide troll who appear once in a while and cause some mess until they get bored. (using either a bot  net or Tor to have changing IP, evading any form of permanent ban)

Comment: after the spam is deleted, the front page shows Community not the original author. I seem to recall asking for that because otherwise offensive or promotional names get advertised, but I can't find it

Comment: Not spam, the spammer who posted the spam. But yeah, I understand now.

Comment: They're fighting a war of independence but the Ottoman Empire is hearing nothing of it. SE is a known propaganda arm of the OE and has been known in the past for intervening in questions relating to Turkish sovereignty, Armenian Genocide and other controversial related subjects.  This comment has been brought to you by the early 20th century, and the letters A and F.

Comment: It's the ghost of Serdar Argic (I'm seriously dating myself...)

Answer (score 16):

Nothing interesting. A bored troll picks some text, runs a search for posts to hit, posts it as an answer. We flag them, they go away. The troll does succeed in vandalizing the homepage, since it's now full of posts with a mention of a specific term.

When the accounts  get destroyed, the bumps get attributed to Community. So it looks like Community "modified" a bunch of things.

Ideally, posts would be "un-bumped" instead of attributing a no longer existing reason for bump to Community... feature-request?

Meanwhile, you may want to retag / edit some of the newer questions to bring them back to the homepage.

Answer (score 8):

Well, a picture says a lot here. This is what the activity on Travel looks like:

> [image]

The accounts all have the same username (but apparently used different emails, as the Gravatar is different each time), which means that they're easy to look up. [Searching Smokey](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?autoflagged=&body=&commit=Search&feedback=&page=1&post_type=&reason=&site=&title=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&username=the+away+days&utf8=%E2%9C%93&why=), it appears there were **120** spam posts network-wide from these accounts (all within 16 hours). The deluge stopped four hours ago.

(According to that list, it was mostly posts about Turkey the country that were spammed, but there were also some posts that were just about music that were targeted.)

There's not much more to do about this except tell moderators to delete the spam accounts.

Comment: I believe every user has been deleted.

Comment: @GrantGarrison I checked several sites and I think History is the only one where the accounts were deleted.

Comment: I know @undo or some SO moderator got to the SO accounts. I will check through and ping some mods in CHQ to get rid of the rest.